# My problem is regarding Jmeter when I am trying to use the non-GUI mode

Tags: jmeter

When I am passing the command in command prompt then I am getting the below error-

```
    C:\Users\ShivangiT\Downloads\apache-jmeter-5.3\apache-jmeter-5.3\bin>Jmeter.bat -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml -n -t \Users\ShivangiT\Downloads\apache-jmeter-5.3\apache-jmeter-5.3\bin\vieweventpage.jmx -l \Users\ShivangiT\Downloads\apache-jmeter-5.3\apache-jmeter-5.3\bin\rr.jtl
Creating summariser <summary>
Created the tree successfully using \Users\ShivangiT\Downloads\apache-jmeter-5.3\apache-jmeter-5.3\bin\vieweventpage.jmx
Starting standalone test @ Fri Aug 21 07:29:38 BST 2020 (1597991378434)
Waiting for possible Shutdown/StopTestNow/HeapDump/ThreadDump message on port 4445
summary =     41 in 00:00:14 =    2.9/s Avg:  5256 Min:     7 Max: 13688 Err:    13 (31.71%)
Tidying up ...    @ Fri Aug 21 07:29:52 BST 2020 (1597991392905)
... end of run
The JVM should have exited but did not.
The following non-daemon threads are still running (DestroyJavaVM is OK):
Thread[DestroyJavaVM,5,main], stackTrace:
Thread[AWT-EventQueue-0,6,main], stackTrace:sun.misc.Unsafe#park
java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport#park
java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject#await
java.awt.EventQueue#getNextEvent
java.awt.EventDispatchThread#pumpOneEventForFilters
java.awt.EventDispatchThread#pumpEventsForFilter
java.awt.EventDispatchThread#pumpEventsForHierarchy
java.awt.EventDispatchThread#pumpEvents
java.awt.EventDispatchThread#pumpEvents
java.awt.EventDispatchThread#run

Thread[AWT-Shutdown,5,system], stackTrace:java.lang.Object#wait
sun.awt.AWTAutoShutdown#run
java.lang.Thread#run
```

Can anybody please help me with this.

Comment: Hello, any update on answer? if ok you should accept it and upvote so that it’s helpful to others. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is a known issue of JMeter 5.3 when test plan contains Http(s) Test script recorder.

The workaround is to remove it.

See:

- https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=64479

Alternatively you can try nightly build:

- https://ci.apache.org/projects/jmeter/nightlies/

Answer (score -2):

Shiva, I would suggest that you should use the older version of JMeter always. The reason is very simple. There is not much of a change in JMeter since JMeter 4. JMeter is more inclined towards its compatibility with JDK 11 as currently, it supports JDK 8 flawlessly in the older versions. Use JMeter 4 from the [JMeter official archive](https://archive.apache.org/dist/jmeter/binaries/) and you'll be able to execute everything smoothly. No need to look for workarounds. Make sure you use JMeter 4

Comment: There are a lot of changes since JMeter 5.3, see https://jmeter.apache.org/changes.html and https://jmeter.apache.org/changes_history.html JMeter 4 suffers from more issues than 5.3. It’s bad practice to use old version of Jmeter.

Comment: And do we really use all those things? Load Generation and report Generation won't change. I really dont understand the need to run behind the newer versions always,